# Effect of same social media accounts names on SEO

Tags: seo

Does having multiple social media accounts on other websites with the same name as the main domain name adversely affect SEO?
Our main domain is Blue17.co.uk and other accounts are for example blue17vintage on instagram and Blue17 vintage on Ipernity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No adversely, in fact this practice have been recognised as co-citation in the SEO world.

The effects are claimed to be the same as a name being repeated hundreds of times until it becomes a brand, see were this is going?

According to [this article](https://www.wordtracker.com/blog/link-building/co-citation-and-co-occurrence-in-seo) “It's now best to maximize your brand mentions by using links with branded anchor text” mentioning your business or website name between sites is not just beneficial but encouraged.  Some people believe that SEO has become a PR game. The more your brand is mentioned on the web, the better you’ll perform in search.

Social media channels are a great way to create co-citations and co-occurrence opportunities.

It is claimed that Brand mentions have a power that is similar to backlinks. My advise will be if your are referring to your website in other sites or social media channels make sure your brand or website name, is consistent. This way you will create strong signals to search engines about who you are, what you do and how you want to be recognised.

Comment: Thank you Titico, it's very helpful.Your point about consistency implies that we should use just one name.

Comment: @Blue17 Yes exactly, consistency across citations is the key.